# Convergence of $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+\dfrac{\alpha^2}{16}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $(x_n) _{n\in N}$ defined by $x_0=\dfrac{1}{2}$, and  $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+\dfrac{\alpha^2}{16}$, $\alpha>0$. For what values of $\alpha$ does this sequence converge? diverge? Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$ for $\alpha^2=3$
Any form of directive will help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $l$, then $l = l^2+\alpha^2/16$.

Comment: And hence this directly implies that for all $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|>2$, the sequence diverges. We are left only with the cases to check if the sequence is convergent for $|\alpha|\leq2$, which we can do with hint given by Mr. Gandalf Sauron.

Comment: Right, if $\alpha<2$, $(x_n)$ is decreasing, thus converges, and only one of the roots of the equation is below $1/2$

Comment: $|\alpha| <2$? You missed modulus?

Comment: OP assumes $\alpha>0$

Comment: Oh! Correct. Fine.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $x_{n}\geq 0\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now $x_{n+1}-x_{n}=(x_{n}-x_{n-1})(x_{n}+x_{n-1})$ which is $\geq$ or $\leq$ $0$ as $x_{n}$ is increasing or decreasing. Inductively it boils down to whether $x_{1}>x_{0}$ or $x_{1}<x_{0}$. Then analyzing boundedness for different values of $\alpha$ gives you convergence.

Then you assume limit is $l$ .

Then $l=l^{2}+\frac{\alpha^{2}}{16}$. Solving this quadratic gives you the limit. And using monotonic increasing or decreasing and the bounds you get to conclude which root of this quadratic is actually the limit.

Comment: You cannot bound the sequence in general: if $\alpha=4$, then $x_n$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: The op is asking for a directive and not a solution. The analysis for what values of $\alpha$ we have convergence is for the op to do.

Comment: Before you edited your answer, it seemed (at least to me) like you claimed the sequence was bounded for every $\alpha$. I was simply clearing this up so as to not confuse the OP.

Comment: @Astyx . I agree. I chose my words carelessly. But I think the op would have figured it out given that he would have ended up with complex roots.

Comment: I'm very much grateful. Thanks to you all.